# Big-O Notation (How to calculate C and k)

Tags: algorithms

I have a fair idea of what Big-O Notation is, but I'd like to know if there's a sure fire way to calculate the values of C and k for which

[image]

Example question:

[image]

Via trial and error, I have found them out to be C = 4, k = 9. Is there a specific method to calculate these values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a specific method to calculate these values?

No.

In the case you explain though, for every $x\geqslant1$, $x^4+9x^3+4x+7\leqslant x^4+9x^4+4x^4+7x^4$ hence $k=1$ and $C=21$ fit.

Likewise (*exercise*), $k=2$ and $C=7$ would fit. Or $k=5$ and $C=4$. Or many others.

Comment: So we can have multiple values of C and k for which the equality holds true?

Comment: @Rafay Yes! This is a vitally useful insight.  Notice that in Did's answer $k=1$ was not calculated, but chosen  specifically to ensure that $x^4 \ge x^3 \ge x^2 \ge x \ge 1$ as long as $x\ge k$.  You'll find it takes much less effort to find a working $C$ if you allow yourself the freedom of increasing $k$ when it's advantageous.

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific general method to calculate these values. In this case you  could fix any $C$ greater than $1$ and then determine a $k$ via solving the resulting (in)equality.

However, please note that the point here is not at all  to find *optimal* values; basically you can take whathever works conveniently. Normally, one uses this asymptotic notation precisely when one does not care about the fine details but just wants a rough idea.